# print full result of cmd findstr?

Tags: command-prompt

Basically I am trying to find out where is python `SimpleHTTPServer.py` located at.

So I did `cd \ && dir /s |findstr SimpleHTTPServer.py` With that, I do receive some results but can't tell where the location of the file is.

```
C:\>dir /s |findstr SimpleHTTPServer.py
2015-01-02  02:23 PM             7,974 SimpleHTTPServer.py
2019-03-02  03:17 PM             7,997 SimpleHTTPServer.py
2019-03-14  05:47 PM             7,823 SimpleHTTPServer.pyc
2019-03-02  03:17 PM             7,997 SimpleHTTPServer.py
```

Answer (score 0):

As Usual Have to answer my own question, I was googling findstr while I should have done `dir`.

This worked for me `dir /s/b |findstr "SimpleHTTPServer.py"`